# Centering a paragraph of text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

How can I have a paragraph in simple text (no math, no equations or symbols) to be centered at the middle of the page so that the lines begin aligned on the left?

Comment: What exactly does "centered at the middle of the page" refer to here? Vertically centered or horizontally centered? If it refers to the later doesn't that contradict the second requirement "lines begin aligned on the left"? Please clarify. Probably a sketch of the expected output would also help here.

Comment: `\clearpage \vspace*{\fill}  text text ... text \vspace*{\fill}\clearpage` ? (but if you do mean that, this is vertical-alignment not horizontal-alignment)

Comment: `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}`.

Comment: great, Mico's answer is exactly what i wanted.